# MCU Espresso: Program behave unexpectedly when compiled using a different offset than 0x00

Tags: compiler-errors, linker, embedded, bootloader, nxp-microcontroller

I am testing my bootloader project for KL46, so i tried compiling some applications to specific addresses (0x20000) using my linker file. The linker files i used is exactly a copy from the one generated by MCU Espresso but only change the top definition part like this rather than starting flash from 0x00.

```
`>! MEMORY
>! {
>! Define each memory region */
>! PROGRAM_FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000, LENGTH = 0x7800 /* 256K bytes (alias Flash) */
>! SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x1fffe000, LENGTH = 0x8000 /* 32K bytes (alias RAM) */
>! }
>!     __base_PROGRAM_FLASH = 0x20000 ; /* PROGRAM_FLASH */
>!     __base_Flash = 0x20000 ; /* Flash */
>!     __top_PROGRAM_FLASH = 0x20000 + 0x7800 ;
>!     __top_Flash = 0x20000 + 0x7800 ;
>!     __base_SRAM = 0x1fffe000 ; /* SRAM */
>!     __base_RAM = 0x1fffe000 ; /* RAM */
>!     __top_SRAM = 0x1fffe000 + 0x8000 ; /* 32K bytes */
>!     __top_RAM = 0x1fffe000 + 0x8000 ; /* 32K bytes */
>! `
```

Although the program compiled and ide flashed the program code correctly to 0x20000,  when i debug it just jumping back and forth from Reset ISR to man and back to Reset. Please help me, i look into the assembly code and saw nothing wrong, do i need to change anything else in the linker file.

I was expecting it to run normally, i also checked the disassembly but i have no clue why it just jumping between main and Reset ISR

Comment: "rather than starting flash from 0x00" Well... do you actually know what's stored at address 0 on a Cortex M? Because it isn't just program memory but also the vector table and misc fundamental boot-up stuff. How do you flash the vector table? If you don't then the SP won't get set correctly.

Comment: Why is your flash length only 30K bytes?  If it is linking and the link map shows everything in the expected place, then the issue is with your code (bootloader or application), but you have chosen not to show that.  There is no "Reset ISR", the reset vector is the address loaded to the PC on reset, it is not a "service routine".  How are you loading the PC and SP to perform the jump to the application code?  Are disabling interrupts before making that jump?  Are you  relocating the vector table to that of the application before the jump?  Occam's Razor suggests the code not the link/locate.

Comment: In the above question: 
1. I tried to use MCUXpressoIDE to Flash my program code to a specific address in flash and use the ide debugger to run the program. I am working on FRDM KL46 board so, if you don't change the linker, program code is auto load in Flash 0x00 address.
2. I am just testing on some blink LED and switch program 30kb is more than enough.
3. I FOUND OUT the error: when I use my Bootloader code to run the program at 0x20000 it worked, but run directly using IDE didn't. That becauses the Debugger set the Vector table Offset (VTOR register) wrong.

Comment: 4. In my first version of Bootloader code i made the same mistake of setting the vector table offset wrong. In the Arm Cortex M0+ manual VTOR part is a bit confusing, It said that the SCB_VTOR register bit 0-6 is reserved so I wrote SCB->VTOR = (OFFSET << 6). But that is not true, you just need  SCB->VTOR = OFFSET; (in this case OFFSET = 0x20000) and the code will works just fine.